# Removing vowels from a String (Scheme)

Tags: scheme

I know the basic algorithm for this problem but I am having trouble changing the sentence into a list inside my conditional. I created make-list to make it easier on myself but I'm not sure where to put it in the code. For ex, in the first cond statement, I need the sentence to be a list before I check if the first element in the sentence is a vowel.. but I have been doing it syntactically wrong.

vowel-ci? returns #t if a character is a case insensitive vowel, and #f otherwise.

stenotype takes a sentence and returns it with all vowels removed.

```
(define make-list
   (lambda (string)
     (string->list string)))

(define stenotype
  (lambda (sentence)
    (cond
      [(vowel-ci? (car sentence)) (stenotype (cdr sentence))]
      [else (cons (car sentence) (stenotype (cdr sentence)))])))
```

Comment: Is stenotype supposed to return a list or a string?

Comment: Note that `make-list` is effectively an alias for `string->list`, though if it helps you to get a grasp on the solution, it serves a valued purpose.

Comment: stenotype returns the string with all the vowels removed. Right. So I would need to convert the list into a string again too.

Comment: Yeah outis, I just did that to help myself. I'm just not sure how to turn the string into a list before I check the conditionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different tasks (preparing input so it can be processed by your implementation and the processing itself), which you've broken into two different functions. The next step is combining the functions, rather than rewriting the latter to use the former. The simplest way of combining functions is composition. Compose `make-list` and `stenotype` (you may wish to name this composition) and you'll have your solution.

```
(define double
    (lambda (x) (* x 2)))

(define inc
    (lambda (x) (+ x 1)))

; one option: define a new function that's a composition    
(define double-inc
    (lambda (x) (inc (double x))))

; another option: compose the functions when you use them
(inc (double 23))

; yet another option: make the other functions local to the composition
; Useful if the other functions are subordinate to the composition, and 
; aren't useful outside of it. You often see this with recursive functions,
; where the outer function sets up a call to the recursive function
(define (double-inc x)
    (define (double x) (* x 2))
    (define (inc x) (+ x 1))
  (inc (double x)))

(define (max numbers)
    (define (max-recur maximum numbers)
      (cond ((eq? numbers '()) maximum)
            ((< maximum (car numbers)) (max-recur (car numbers) (cdr numbers)))
            (else (max-recur maximum (cdr numbers)))))
  (max-recur (car numbers) (cdr numbers)))
```

Note that you're missing a base case in `stenotype` to end the recursion.

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I swear I got it working a second ago, then I messed something up. hah. But yeah, that was a good tip. I changed stenotype to stenotype-helper and then was able to combine them like this:  (list->string (stenotype (string->list sentence)))))

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the string to a list only once and filter out the vowels using `map` or recursion. The following procedure shows how to use `map`:

```
(define (remove-vowels str) 
    (let ((res ()))
      (map (lambda (c) (if (not (vowel? c)) (set! res (append res (list c))))) 
           (string->list str))
      (list->string res)))
```

This one is recursive and avoids `set!` and `append`:

```
(define (remove-vowels str)
    (let loop ((slist (string->list str)) (res ()))
      (if (not (null? slist))
          (if (vowel-ci? (car slist))
              (loop (cdr slist) res)
              (loop (cdr slist) (cons (car slist) res)))
          (list->string (reverse res)))))
```

Usage:

```
> (remove-vowels "hello, world")
"hll, wrld"
> (remove-vowels "goodbye cruel world")
"gdby crl wrld"
```

Comment: "filter out the vowels using map or recursion ..." What about using `filter`? :)

Comment: @knivil There is no `filter` procedure in standard Scheme. (http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs.html). It might be available as an extension in some implementations.

Comment: There's filter in Petite Chez Scheme, the version that I'm using. We actually just learned about it right after I submitted my answer. But from my understanding, filter gives you what you're looking for.. so in this case it would return the vowels instead of removing them.. Unless (not (filter)) exists. That would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define make-list (string)

     (string->list string))

(cond
[(empty? make-list(sentence))empty]
      [(vowel-ci? (car make-list(sentence))) 
        (stenotype list->string ((cdr make-  list(sentence))))]
      [else (cons (car make-list(sentence)) (stenotype (cdr make-list(sentence))))])))
```

Comment: Oh I see, you have to change it into a list @ every line. That's annoying :]