# PHP Strip vowels from string

Tags: php

For directory-naming algorithm, need to strip vowels (and white space) from string to shorten dir names.

Found this thread [Removing vowels from a String (Scheme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160773/removing-vowels-from-a-string-scheme) but cannot figure out how to turn it into a usable function. FORGET THAT THREAD - it's not PHP. Sorry all.

Any thoughts on a PHP solution, then?

Comment: Because that question posts code in a different language...

Comment: Are you kidding ? This is not even the same language.

Comment: Right, I just realized that. I knew I was a novice at PHP, but that was totally over my head. However, it was a suggested "possible duplicate" when I was posting this question, so I assumed...

Comment: I would use a whitelist instead of a blacklist. You don't want characters like `/` or `..` in your allowed directory names...

Comment: Various methods for multiple search-replace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433754/methods-to-remove-specific-characters-from-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using string replace?

```
$yourString = "FileNameOf Hello";
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", " ");
$yourString = str_replace($vowels, "", $yourString);
echo $yourString; //FlNmfHll
```

Comment: I didn't even finish revising the question before you had the answer. There's gotta be a badge for *that*. Answer accepted. (Apparently I must wait 7 minutes, so says the orange pop-up box).

Comment: @gibberish Glad to be able to help.

Comment: you could use str_ireplace() and cut the $vowels length in half :)

Answer (score 11):

I wonder do you really need a function here when it can be done with a single regex. For example:

```
$some_dirname = 'This is a wonderful dirname';
$pure_dirname = preg_replace('#[aeiou\s]+#i', '', $some_dirname);
print $pure_dirname; // Thsswndrfldrnm
```

The trick is to run regex replace over your string, removing all the characters in so-called `character range` (defined with [] syntax).

I've used '/i' modifier to remove capitalized vowels as well.

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

```
$oldStr = "Some string";
$newStr = str_ireplace(array('a','e','i','o','u',' '), '', $oldStr);
```

Comment: AH! Even more elegant than the accepted answer. Thank you! UPVOTE.

Comment: Is there any qucik way to make it avoid the first character for match?

Comment: @Achshar this on third line: `$newStr = (stristr('aeiou ', $oldStr[0]) === FALSE) ? $newStr : $oldStr[0].$newStr;`

Answer (score 0):

String Translate in php helps in removing the string :

strtr — Translate characters or replace substrings

`$string    = "voweltest";`
`$trans = array("a" => "","e"=>"","i"=>"","o"=>"","u"=>"");`
`echo strtr($string, $trans);`

`Output : vwltst`